# Selendroid 0.5.1 on Windows: getting INSTRUMENTATION_FAILED

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3, appium, selendroid

I am working on a Phonegap/Cordova 3.0 Android (hybrid) app and want to do UI testing. I tried running Appium and Selendroid (http://selendroid.io/) I run on Win 8.1 x64, and am using Visual Studio 2012 with Selenium 2.37 nuget package to write the tests.

The app is loaded OK, along with selendroid in my Android emulator running through eclipse.

I get this error when trying to start up the app through the tool. Any ideas?

```
android.util.AndroidException: INSTRUMENTATION_FAILED:
com.example.femmapp.selendroid/io.selendroid.ServerInstrumentation
```

The error message and stack trace is:

```
A session is either terminated or not started (Original error:
android.util.AndroidException: I
) (NoSuchDriver)AILED:
com.example.femmapp.selendroid/io.selendroid.ServerInstrumentation
   at
OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response
errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String
driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities
desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor
commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(Uri remoteAddress,
ICapabilities desiredCapabilities, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at FEMM.IntegrationTests.TestDriverSetup.TestDriverSetUp(Int32 minutes,
Int32 seconds, String apppkg, String devname, String devv
ers, String webdrvr, String activity, Boolean saucelabs) in c:\mydir
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use selendroid directly?

If you have setup everything, you find a complete sample project of a cordova hybrid app here: https://github.com/selendroid/demoproject-selendroid#hybrid-app-test

In order to get the latest updates, I recommend you to use the latest snapshot version of selendroid: http://ci.selendroid.io/job/selendroid/io.selendroid$selendroid-standalone/

Answer (score 0):

1. check your capability settings, if your appPackage is wrong?
2. remove all the apks related to appium, then retry.
3. remove all the temp files in C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp, then retry.

Hope it helps.